# AKMIDICallbackInstrument handling more than 16 channels

Tags: audiokit, coremidi

I've been using AKMIDICallbackInstrument for connecting a single Audio Unit to Apple's sequencer. This has worked fine in the past, but I now want to extend this into a multi-timbral context. Since the AKMIDICallback only allows for passing `(status, note, velocity)`, I'm not sure how to handle > 16 parts/tracks. I understand that the callback instrument is connected to a track using the endpoint, so that the passed events will only be those from the connected track, but how can I route those events to a specific Audio Unit, other than by MIDI channel? (With Apple's sequencer I could, in principle, have hundreds of tracks, all sending on MIDI channel 1...)

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... okay, I had tried getting around the limitations of the closure by overriding `receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber:velocity:channel:portID:offset:)`, but I suppose that's only for receiving raw MIDI bytes from hardware.

The solution is to override `play(noteNumber:velocity:channel:)`. Since this is an instance method (not a closure) you can reference `self` to handle the events coming through as required (i.e., "self" can point to the desired Audio Unit). I'm actually not using `AKMIDICallbackInstrument` anymore, just subclassing `AKMIDIInstrument`... Seems better suited to my purposes.